# What is Lion's version of Perl 5?

Tags: macos, perl

What version of Perl 5 is OS X Lion shipping with?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

5.12.3 - exactly:

```
Vigor14:~ clt$ uname -a
Darwin Vigor14 11.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.0.0: Sat Jun 18 12:56:35 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.22.73~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
Vigor14:~ clt$ 

Vigor14:~ clt$ /usr/bin/perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 12 subversion 3) configuration:

  Platform:
    osname=darwin, osvers=11.0, archname=darwin-thread-multi-2level
    uname='darwin fifth.apple.com 11.0 darwin kernel version 11.0.0: sun may 29 13:02:55 pdt 2011; root:xnu-1699.22.44~4release_x86_64 x86_64 '
    config_args='-ds -e -Dprefix=/usr -Dccflags=-g  -pipe  -Dldflags= -Dman3ext=3pm -Duseithreads -Duseshrplib -Dinc_version_list=none -Dcc=llvm-gcc-4.2'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=define, use64bitall=define, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='llvm-gcc-4.2', ccflags ='-arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include',
    optimize='-Os',
    cppflags='-g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=8, ptrsize=8, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=16
    ivtype='long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='llvm-gcc-4.2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7', ldflags ='-arch x86_64 -arch i386 -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib /usr/lib
    libs=-ldbm -ldl -lm -lutil -lc
    perllibs=-ldl -lm -lutil -lc
    libc=, so=dylib, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl.dylib
    gnulibc_version=''
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=bundle, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags=' '
    cccdlflags=' ', lddlflags='-arch x86_64 -arch i386 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: MULTIPLICITY PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV
                        PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT PERL_MALLOC_WRAP USE_64_BIT_ALL
                        USE_64_BIT_INT USE_ITHREADS USE_LARGE_FILES
                        USE_PERLIO USE_PERL_ATOF USE_REENTRANT_API
  Locally applied patches:
    /Library/Perl/Updates/<version> comes before system perl directories
    installprivlib and installarchlib points to the Updates directory
  Built under darwin
  Compiled at Jun 13 2011 14:45:31
  %ENV:
    PERLBREW_HOME="/Users/clt/.perlbrew"
    PERLBREW_PATH="/Users/clt/perl5/perlbrew/bin"
    PERLBREW_ROOT="/Users/clt/perl5/perlbrew"
    PERLBREW_VERSION="0.27"
  @INC:
    /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Library/Perl/5.12
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.12
    /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3
    /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/5.12
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12
    .
Vigor14:~ clt$
```

Just compiled perlbrew with the new Xcode (downloaded from the AppStore):

```
Vigor14:~ clt$ perlbrew install perl-5.14.1
Fetching perl-5.14.1 as /Users/clt/perl5/perlbrew/dists/perl-5.14.1.tar.gz
Installing /Users/clt/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.14.1 into ~/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.1

This could take a while. You can run the following command on another shell to track the status:

  tail -f ~/perl5/perlbrew/build.log

Installed /Users/clt/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.14.1 as perl-5.14.1 successfully. Run the following command to switch to it.

  perlbrew switch perl-5.14.1
```

compiler:

```
Vigor14:~ clt$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2335.15~25/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2335.15~25/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)
```

Comment: and the compiler seems to be `llvm-gcc-4.2` which I think means it is `gcc` frontending `llvm` as opposed to `clang`.

Comment: Can you check what compiler it used?  I assume `llvm-gcc-4.2`, but I am curious.